# Python: Replace character RANGE in a string with new string

Tags: python, string, character

Given the following string:

`mystring = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"`

The goal is to swap out a character position range with other characters.

For example, swap out characters 20-24 with `ABCDE`. 
The result would look like:

`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXABCDEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Testing:

```
mystring = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
mystring[20:24] = 'ABCDE'
```

I get the error: `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

**The end goal is a reusable function such as:**

```
def replace_chars(some_string, start_char, end_char, replace_string):
    if len(replace_string) == (end_char_pos - start_char_pos + 1):
        some_string[start_char:end_char] = replace_string
    else:
        print "replace string invalid length"
        sys.exit(1)
    return mystring

new_string = replace_chars('XYZXYZ', 2, 4, 'AAA')
```

I realize that it's possible to pad out the unchanged range into a new string:

```
mystring = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
mystring = mystring[0:19] + 'ABCDE' + mystring[25:38]
```

However that will force more calculation and since this will be happening thousands of times against lines in a file. The different lines will be different length and will be different character positions to swap. Doing this seems like it would be a long workaround where I should just be able to insert direct into the character positions in-place.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Is this code meant to be used in biology?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

strings are immutable (unchangeable).  But you can index and join items.

```
mystring = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
mystring = 'ABCDE'.join([mystring[:20],mystring[24:]])
```

> 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXABCDEXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

Do be careful as the string length "ABCDE" and the number of items you omit between mystring[:20], mystring[24:] need to be the same length.

Comment: @ScottHunter I haven't timed it, but I imagine that `''.join` is faster than string concatenation for long strings.

Comment: Does that take into account the time spent *making* the list?

Comment: If this is for biology then this is the wrong approach.  There is libraries for this specifically.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, you could get a slight improvement by skipping the list and doing `mystring = 'ABCDE'.join([mystring[:20],mystring[24:]])`

Comment: @mypetlion go ahead and edit the code.  (get the points for being an editor.)

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest method, really like the `join()` to pad the replacement string. Very similar to my workaround but cleaner. 
Will also add safety checks to ensure the replacement matches the character range.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in python! You'll have to split the string into three pieces and concatenate them together :)

```
mystring = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
new_str = "ABCDE"
first_piece = mystring[0:20]
third_piece = mystring[24:len(mystring)]
final_string = first_piece + new_str + third_piece
```

Comment: Isn't this just what OP posted as a "workaround" without naming the first and third pieces?

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly possible in python, but consider using [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) a similar structure to a string in python, with a key difference being mutability

```
In [52]: my_stuff = bytearray('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

In [53]: my_stuff = my_stuff[0:19] + "abcd" + my_stuff[25:38]

In [54]: print my_stuff
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXabcdXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

There are some key things you should know when using a bytearray, you can see some of them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable)

Answer (score -4):

As much as you think you should be able to assign to individual characters of a string, `'str' object does not support item assignment` says you can't.

Comment: I think they realize that they can't. They're looking for a solution that is allowed, but will produce the result they want.

Comment: "I should just be able to insert direct into the character positions in-place" suggests otherwise.  OP *has* a solution to produce the desired result, but doesn't like its mechanics.